# Is there a performance difference between using IN ('ABC') and = 'ABC' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

Is there a performance difference between the two queries below?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name IN ('ABC');

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = ('ABC');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no there is no difference between `IN` and `=`  for single value. you can check query execution plan using [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html):

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name IN ('ABC');

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Answer (score -1):

No. I believe MySQL rewrites `x IN (a, b, c)` to `x = a OR x = b OR x = c` internally, so it's the same query.

Comment: It doesn't do that. The "or" version does not use an index, the "in" version does. Big difference